# In NativeScript, why do I get an error 'Invalid character @'?

Tags: vue.js, nativescript

I'm trying to get the following codebase:

https://github.com/andreliem/vue-nativescript-getting-started

working in the NativeScript Playground.

So far, I have:

https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-vue&id=TTgcmi&v=18

but the following line in the .scss file:

```
@import '~nativescript-theme-core/scss/skins/light/index';
```

is generating an error "Invalid character: `@`"

How do I fix this error?

Comment: Where do you see the invalid character error? In Playground / Preview app? Also Vue Router it totally experimental so manual router is recommended at the moment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to update {NS} and all the dependencies here. That codebase is 5 months old and still using older version of CSS loader where this problem was there.

Run the `tns update` and follow the [instructions](https://docs.nativescript.org/releases/upgrade-instructions) here.